# How to solve "error C2078: too many initializers" when moving the same members from the parent class to its child?

Tags: c++, inheritance, initialization, initializer-list, aggregate-initialization

I am facing a relatively tricky situation here that seemed quite easy at first sight. After moving those three members from the parent class `Parent` to its child class `Child` it seems that I'm no longer able to take advantage of the default constructor.

Why? And is there a way out here without having to specifically implement a Child(...) constructor. Seems counterintuitive at first... Actually I would have thought that the first example is where it fails (thinking that the Child class' constructor would overshadow the one of its parent).

```
struct Parent
{
    std::string mText;
    int mInt;
    bool mBool;
};

struct Child : public Parent
{
};

Child test{ "", 0, false}; // Compiles
```

But in this latter case, the default constructor won't be created if the members are defined in the child class.

```
struct Parent
{
};

struct Child : public Parent
{
    std::string mText;
    int mInt;
    bool mBool;
};

Child test{ "", 0, false}; // error C2078: too many initializers
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need empty braces for the base subobject in [aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization). (Default constructor is irrelevant in this case, both `Parent` and `Child` are aggregate and aggregate initialization gets performed.)

> However, if the object has a sub-aggregate without any members (an empty struct, or a struct holding only static members), brace elision is not allowed, and an empty nested list `{}` must be used.

```
Child test{ {}, "", 0, false};
//          ^^
```

Comment: It works! I see, the default constructor obviously must refer to Parent::Parent()

Comment: @tbop Default constructor is irrelevant here; you're using aggregate initialization.

Comment: Bonus question: given children is a std::vector<Child>, why would the line here not compile?

children.emplace_back({}, "", 0, false); // doesn't compile

Comment: @tbop Brace-init-list like `{}` is evil; it doesn't have type and cause template argument deduction for `emplace_back` failing. You can use `children.emplace_back(Parent{}, "", 0, false);` instead.